# Interface inside fragment returns null value

Tags: android, android-fragments

> In onAttach() method **communicator =(Communicator) activity** returns null. When i click on the Image View it shows the value of **communicatior** is null.
>   I have check but not able to resolve the problem. Here in the fragment when click on the image view some data should transfer to the activity. But the reference variable of Interface Commnunicator communicator gets the null value in **onAttch()**

```
public class SendFragment extends Fragment  {
ImageView imgContact;
TextView tvContactName;
String username;
Communicator communicator;

public interface Communicator {
    public void sendDataToActivity(String s);
}

public static final String TAG = SendFragment.class.getSimpleName();


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof Communicator) {
        communicator = (Communicator) context;
    } else {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Must implement " + TAG + ".Communicator on caller Activity");
    }
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_send, container, false);
    imgContact = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactbook);
    tvContactName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvcontactname);

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
        username = getArguments().getString("username").toString();
        tvContactName.setText(username);
    }

    listeners();

    return view;
}


private void listeners() {
    imgContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            communicator.sendDataToActivity(Constants.selectUserName);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AllContactsListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Now the below is my Code of the activity..

```
public class AllContactsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, SendFragment.Communicator,RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClick {
Context context;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager recylerViewLayoutManager;
ImageButton btnSliding_common;

DrawerLayout drawer;
NavigationView navigationView;
String sendFragmentStringFlag;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_contacts_list);
     setIds();
    listeners();


}



private void listeners() {

    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(AllContactsListActivity.this, subjects, emails, address,this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

    RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration =
            new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);



    btnSliding_common.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        }
    });
}

private void setIds() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    btnSliding_common = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSliding_contact);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_contact);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view_contact);

    recylerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recylerViewLayoutManager);
}





@Override
public void sendDataToActivity(String sendMoneyflag) {
    sendFragmentStringFlag=sendMoneyflag;

    }

@Override
public void onClick(String username) {
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(sendFragmentStringFlag)) {
        if (sendFragmentStringFlag.equals(Constants.selectUserName)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("username", username);
            SendFragment sendFragment = new SendFragment();
            sendFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            finish();
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "USER NAME" + username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably because the host activity didn't implement the Fragment interface.

You're trying to attach the interface with the following method:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
  super.onAttach(activity);
  try {
  communicator = (Communicator) activity;
  } catch (Exception e){}
}
```

But you didn't handle the Exception correctly. So, you don't know when the interface is set correctly. And you also override `onAttach(Activity activity)` which is now deprecated.

You need to change the code as following:

```
public static final String TAG = YourFragment.class.getSimpleName();
...

@Override 
public void onAttach(Context context) {
  super.onAttach(context);
  if (context instanceof Communicator) {
    communicator = (Communicator) context;
  } else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Must implement " + TAG + ".Communicator on caller Activity");
  }
}
```

It will throw error if your host activity didn't implement the interface.

You also need to attach the fragment to your activity by using FragmentTransaction. Something like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

SendFragment sendFragment = new SendFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, sendFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: after implementing your code it is showing exception like " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must implement SendFragment.Communicator on caller Activity"..

Comment: That's a correct behaviour. It means that you didn't implement the interface in your host Activity. Your activity class should be defined as something like this: `public class YourActivity extends Activity implements YouFragment.Communicator {}`

Comment: I have already implemented the same. But i am getting the same exception. **"public class AllContactsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, SendFragment.Communicator,RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClick**"

Comment: That's weird.. Could you update your question with the implemented code?

Comment: I've found the reason for the problem. You're forget to attach you fragment to the activity with: `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, yourFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();`

Comment: @GyanSAwasthi: But why you create the Fragment then exited the activity? If you finish the activity, the fragment will be destroyed.

Comment: SendFragement is attached with different activity . Let me explain DashBoard contains SendFragment and SendFragment is comunicating with AllContactsListActivity. Dashboard activity contains viewpager where SendFragment is the one of part of viewpager. Now we need to communicate with SendFragment to AllContactsListActivity by using Interface. Please guide me.

Comment: ohh, I see. You need to use publisher/subscriber pattern then. You can use EventBus for your case. Using interface there will make your application becomes so complex.